# Setting y-axis values with big intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display my data with values like `1.0e+10, 1.0e+11, 1.0e+12, .. , 1.0e+19` in the y-axis. So I've tried to specify the y-axis values by doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick


data = [1e+10, 1e+15, 1e+13, 4e+10, 3e+12, 6e+11,
        7e+14, 8e+13, 9e+12, 10e+16, 11e+17, 12e+18, 13e+19]
axes = plt.axes()
plt.plot(range(1, 14), data)

bottom = 1e+10
top = 1e+19

plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 14, 1))
plt.yticks([1.0e+10, 1.0e+11, 1.0e+12, 1.0e+13, 1.0e+14,
            1.0e+15, 1.0e+16, 1.0e+17, 1.0e+18, 1.0e+19])

axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1e'))

plt.show()
```

The result was not as intended.
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8HiV.png)

After, I've tried to limit the y-axis values by specifying the bottom and top values, so that the y-axis values would be between these values. The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

data = [1e+10, 1e+15, 1e+13, 4e+10, 3e+12, 6e+11,
        7e+14, 8e+13, 9e+12, 10e+16, 11e+17, 12e+18, 13e+19]
axes = plt.axes()
plt.plot(range(1, 14), data)

bottom = 1e+10
top = 1e+19

plt.ylim(bottom, top)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 14, 1))
axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1e'))

plt.show()
```

[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uYuZ.png)

What I've got is `1.0e+19` as the top value, but the smallest (bottom) value is not `1e+10` even I limit the y-axis by saying `plt.ylim(bottom, top)`. So, all data can not be visualized. And as can be seen from the right-bottom of the output2 image, y-coordinate of the cursor is `5.4e+15`, shouldn't it be `0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to set the y-scale to logarithmic rather than linear: `plt.yscale('log')`.